# Registro de Errores Linux

Tags: linux, bash, red-hat

como les va.
Tengo un archivo que tiene 5 campos separados por pipes

Ejemplo:

```
0987123443|InfoBasica||Derivación Proceso|8899776673|Cliente 10001144795 no existe.|
```

En el cual el ultimo campo, en este ejemplo seria "Cliente 10001144795 no existe." es el mensaje de error. Los errores no son siempre los mismos y pueden aparecer nuevos errores. Lo que necesitaría es que cada vez que se encuentre un error nuevo, ese ultimo campo se agregue a un archivo. El archivo que contiene errores, no siempre tienen la misma cantidad de líneas, con lo cual un dia pueden aparecer 10, otras veces 900, y asi.

Mas en detalle el archivo podría llegar a venir asi:

```
0987123443|InfoBasica||Derivación Proceso|8899776673|Cliente 10001144795 no existe.|
3246656545|InfoBasica||Derivación Proceso|6587678778|Cliente 12341241243 duplicado.|
3457878784|InfoBasica||Derivación Proceso|5486787867|Cliente 45675467456 duplicado.|
2345326654|InfoBasica||Derivación Proceso|0987090909|Cliente 34543254545 no existe.|
```

Como puedo hacerlo en Linux?

Comment: para leer líneas en un array con un delimitador custom sería algo así  `while IFS='|' read -ra c; do echo "${c[-1]}"; done < archivo.txt`

Comment: delimitador custom?, no es lo que busco, se como obtener el valor del ultimo campo, Lo unico que puede cambiar es el ultimo campo, no el delimitador.

Comment: para eliminar duplicados usando [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Removing-Duplicates-from-Unsorted-Text) sería algo así `awk '! seen[$0]++'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, hay dos palabras claves que tomaré para tratar de ayudarte: delimitador "|", y "último" campo.

Para eso podemos utilizar `awk`. Por ejemplo, utilicemos esto para leer todos tus registros separados por "|":

```
$ awk -F '|' '{print $(NF-1)}' archivo.log
```

Resultando en:

```
Cliente 10001144795 no existe.
Cliente 12341241243 duplicado.
Cliente 45675467456 duplicado.
Cliente 34543254545 no existe.
```

Uticé `$(NF-1)` porque, debido a cómo están escrito tus renglones, no pides el último carcater puesto que este último estaría vacío, sino que pides el penúltimo. **NF** es una variable de `awk` que contiene la cantidad de campos.

Ya después de hacer esto, puedes redirigir la salida de ese comando a un archivo a tu gusto:

```
$ awk -F '|' '{print $(NF-1)}' archivo.log >> archivo.err
```